# Add bulk computer membership

Tags: powershell, active-directory, bulkinsert

Im trying to add multiple compuers (from a txt file) to be part of a certain security group.

sample from input.txt

```
COL7DM2CP1
COLC5RNDP1
```

using the following powershell input:

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\input.txt | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'AMATU.SCCM.Office2010.Std'
```

however im getting the following outpout error:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot find an object with identity: 'COL7DM2CP1' under: 'DC=actuant,DC=pri'.
At C:\Scripts\Add bulk ADcomputer to group.ps1:1 char:36
+ Get-Content C:\Scripts\input.txt | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'AMA ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (COL7DM2CP1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADIdentityN 
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADPrincipalGroupMembership:ProcessRecordOverride,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manageme 
   nt.Commands.AddADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

Comment: Your computer should exist in your AD.

Comment: both test computer are listed in Active Directory, and have been there for at least 2 weeks.  Which is why im puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the Add-PrinicpalGroupMembership does not know what object you are looking for.  It does not query AD for the simple computername, it assumes the FQDN.  If you wanted to pass it just a name, you'll need to give it's full AD Distinguished Name.

An easy way around this is to use Get-ADcomputer and pass that to Add-PrinicpalGroupMembership

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\input.txt | Get-ADComputer | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'AMATU.SCCM.Office2010.Std'
```